# Сравнение двух одинаковых строковых переменных

Tags: java

Почему при сравнении двух одинаковых строковых переменных, значение одной из которых присвоено при инициализации, а другой из стандартного ввода я получаю false.

Пример кода:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word1 = scanner.next(); // "word";
        String word2 = "word";
        boolean result = word1 == word2;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Даже не "возможный дубликат", а "стопудовый"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо!

Comment: no problemo! :)